# icinga-web unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, installation, package

I am trying to install icinga-web and I am getting following error:-

I tried installing both the `icinga-core` and `icinga-idoutils` but I still get this error.

```
apt-get install icinga-web
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 icinga-web : Depends: icinga-core (>= 1.7.0) but 1.6.1-2 is to be installed
              Depends: icinga-idoutils (>= 1.7.0) but 1.6.1-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Just FYI,

```
apt-get install icinga-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  pkg-config libpthread-stubs0 libfontconfig1-dev x11proto-kb-dev xtrans-dev x11proto-input-dev libxpm-dev libfreetype6-dev libxau-dev xorg-sgml-doctools libx11-dev libx11-doc libxcb1-dev x11proto-core-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libpthread-stubs0-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  nagios-nrpe-plugin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  icinga-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 117 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/287 kB of archives.
After this operation, 804 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package icinga-core.
(Reading database ... 38940 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking icinga-core (from .../icinga-core_1.6.1-2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up icinga-core (1.6.1-2) ...
 * There is no configuration file for Icinga.
invoke-rc.d: initscript icinga, action "start" failed.

apt-get install icinga-idoutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  pkg-config libpthread-stubs0 libfontconfig1-dev x11proto-kb-dev xtrans-dev x11proto-input-dev libxpm-dev libfreetype6-dev libxau-dev xorg-sgml-doctools libx11-dev libx11-doc libxcb1-dev x11proto-core-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libpthread-stubs0-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  icinga-idoutils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 117 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/221 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,442 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package icinga-idoutils.
(Reading database ... 38947 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking icinga-idoutils (from .../icinga-idoutils_1.6.1-2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up icinga-idoutils (1.6.1-2) ...
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/icinga-idoutils.conf

Creating config file /etc/dbconfig-common/icinga-idoutils.conf with new version

Creating config file /etc/icinga/ido2db.cfg with new version
granting access to database icinga for icinga-idoutils@localhost: success.
verifying access for icinga-idoutils@localhost: success.
creating database icinga: success.
verifying database icinga exists: success.
populating database via sql...  done.
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
```

This problem is resolved.

I have deleted corrupted packages from (/var/lib/dpkg/status)

[Package system broken - E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](https://askubuntu.com/q/195950/36315)

And re-install all icinga packages again using icinga PPA.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can always accept your answer rather than edit question.